# Fetching version strings in an ordered manner from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which version is mentioned as a column. Version details will be as follows.

version:

```
11.1R1.8
11.1R1.80
11.1R1.9
11.1R1.1
11.1R1.10
11.1R1.2
```

I need to write a query to fetch this in an orderly manner. I tried using like command as below, but it fetches in the same order as above.

```
select * from <table> where version like("11.1R1%");
```

Any inputs on this would be helpful. Exact requirement is to fetch the latest version when 11.1R1 substring is provided as input.

Comment: What ordering would you like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular example:

```
select *
from <table>
where version like('11.1R1%')
order by substring_index(version, '.', -1) + 0 desc
limit 1;
```

The `where` ensures that the part before the `R` and the major version after are the same.

You can also express this as:

```
order by length(version) desc, version desc
```

This doesn't convert the version components to a number.  Once again, it works in your case, because the `where` clause ensures that the leading characters are the same.